# long lines in dict according to PEP8

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style, pep8

I have a dict with long lines (>79) in it, like this:

```
context = {
    "this_is_long_key_from_db": mydict['this_is_long_key_from_db']
}
```

How i correctly split it according to PEP8? I couldnt find answers about this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long lines are > 79 characters, so your example is correct. I've however tested this code with http://pep8online.com/checkresult and get no error:

```
context = {
    "this_is_long_key_from_long_database_name":
        mydict['this_is_long_key_from_long_database_name']
}
```